# Ubuntu intel opencl drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need intel opencl runtime drivers for my ubuntu 14.04 32 bit pc.
I have searched for these drivers but intel's site gives only 64 bit drivers.

So, how can ı install opencl 64bit runtime drivers on ubuntu 14.04 32 BİT ? Or, where can i find opencl 32bit runtime drivers.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: A 32-bit OS cannot run 64-bit software. If there's nothing in the standard Canonical releases and nothing on the web, you will need to install 64-bit Ubuntu. I am slightly surprised that you have found 32-bit software that requires OpenCL.

Comment: For what it's worth Canonical have `beignet-opencl-icd` in my 16.04.1/64-bit - it _may_ be in 32-bit versions.